# Can't access default k3s metrics server from Prometheus-Adapter

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, k3s, metrics-server

I have installed Prometheus-adapter along with the default metrics-server that comes with k3s securely on port 443.

Unfortunately, I get no resources when I query custom.metrics.k8s.io

```
$  kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1" | jq .
{
  "kind": "APIResourceList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "groupVersion": "custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "resources": []
}
```

When I look at the logs of Prometheus-adapter I get `unable to update list of all metrics: unable to fetch metrics for query ...: x509: certificate is valid for localhost, localhost, not metrics-server.kube-system`

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: have you installed Prometheus, Prometheus Operator and Prometheus Adapter thru Helm or YAML ?

Comment: @jmvcollaborator https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/tree/master/manifests/metrics-server these are the resources k3s metrics server has

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm still getting same error `unable to update list of all metrics: unable to fetch metrics for query ...: x509: certificate is valid for localhost, localhost, not metrics-server.kube-system` @jmvcollaborator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue, I had to create [separate certificate](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/) for both metrics-server and adapter. Adapter also has an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/prometheus-adapter/issues/169) about adding capability to ignore cert validation which wasn't merged.

For metrics-server and cert request I used the following:

```
{
  "hosts": [
    "prometheus-adapter",
    "prometheus-adapter.monitoring",
    "prometheus-adapter.monitoring.svc",
    "prometheus-adapter.monitoring.pod",
    "prometheus-adapter.monitoring.svc.cluster.local",
    "prometheus-adapter.monitoring.pod.cluster.local",
    "<pod ip>",
    "<service ip>"
  ],
  "CN": "prometheus-adapter.monitoring.pod.cluster.local",
  "key": {
    "algo": "ecdsa",
    "size": 256
  },
}
```

```
{
  "hosts": [
    "metrics-server",
    "metrics-server.kube-system",
    "metrics-server.kube-system.svc",
    "metrics-server.kube-system.pod",
    "metrics-server.kube-system.svc.cluster.local",
    "metrics-server.kube-system.pod.cluster.local",
    "<service ip>",
    "<pod ip>"
  ],
  "CN": "metrics-server.kube-system",
  "key": {
    "algo": "ecdsa",
    "size": 256
  },
}
```

For ca, you can create your certificate authority or use Kubernetes signers as indicated [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/#kubernetes-signers)
The only point worth noting here is that if you use either of signers, you should mount the ca bundle yourself to your deployments.

Finally, mount tls keys and ca bundle to your deployment.

```
  extraArguments:
    - --tls-cert-file=/var/run/serving-cert/tls.crt
    - --tls-private-key-file=/var/run/serving-cert/tls.key
    - --client-ca-file=/etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two main options here:

1. Configure Prometheus to ignore ssl, setting to true the skip verify

> tls_config:
> insecure_skip_verify: true

2. Add the certificate to the scrape_configs under tls_config

> tls_config:
> ca_file: /path/to/prometheus.crt

UPDATE:

On metrics-server-deployment.yaml

1. Leave internalip only, on the --kubelet-preferred-address-type

> --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP